# Java Play Junit: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: junit, playframework-2.3

I am getting the following error while running my play tests in the console.

```
[error] Uncaught exception when running UserTest: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.junit.runner.Request.classes([Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/junit/runner/Request;
sbt.ForkMain$ForkError: org.junit.runner.Request.classes([Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/junit/runner/Request;
    at com.novocode.junit.JUnitRunner$1.execute(JUnitRunner.java:122)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:294)
    at sbt.ForkMain$Run$2.call(ForkMain.java:284)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
```

even an empty test case is not running.

```
public class UserTest  {
    @Test
    public void addUser() {
        assertEquals(1,1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the `classes` method was added to the `Request` class on Junit version 4.6. I tried adding the following to the build.sbt file.

```
libraryDependencies += "junit" % "junit" % "4.8"
```

But it still didnt resolve the issue. Then I downloaded the jar and added it to the lib directory as an unmanaged resource. It seemed to do the trick and I am not getting any Errors now.